# Add a trailing slash to a URL using Apache Rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, apache2

I moved a forum from `subdomain.example.com` to `example.com/directory`

The apache permanent redirect in `subdomain.example.com.conf` works and sends folks to `example.com/directory` no problem.

I am hoping to find a rewrite solution for links shared on the forum with `subdomain.example.com` as the base URL, now that it is located at `example.com/directory`

Clicking a link in the forum to `subdomain.example.com/page.php?id=100` goes to `example.com/directorypage.php?id=100`

Can I force a trailing slash after `example.com/directory`? Is that a bad practice?

Alternatively I can find and replace all instances of `subdomain.example.com` in the database with the desired URL, but thought a rewrite in one of the `conf` or `.htaccess` files might be a better solution.

**EDIT:**

How I fixed it using htaccess...

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^directorypage\.php$ https://example.com/directory/page.php?%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What rule did you use to redirect from the subdomain?  It sounds like it could be improved.

Comment: Can probably still be improved but I got it fixed! Not elegantly. I'll update the question with the fix I am using...